# Make directory and upload multiple file into created directory PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, server, multiple-file-upload, move-uploaded-file

I have been digging for an answer for many days. how do i upload multiple file to the newly created directory. If you look into **file_upload.php** you will find two `$upload_dir` variable. So, let's call first `$upload_dir` as direct folder and Second, `$upload_dir` as make dir. Simple

So, When I select first `$upload_dir` it does upload all files directly into the folder and When I select second `$upload_dir` what it does is create a random folder but unable to upload any file.

I want to upload multiple file into newly created folder

I did refer this [PHP - Upload multiple photos into newly created Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555422/php-upload-multiple-photos-into-newly-created-directory) and [Multiple file upload and store them in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203353/multiple-file-upload-and-store-them-in-a-directory) but didn't work for me

**index.php**

```
<form action="file_upload.php" method="POST"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  
        <h2>Upload Files</h2> 
          
        <p> 
            Select files to upload:  
              
            <!-- name of the input fields are going to 
                be used in our php script-->
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple> 
              
            <br><br> 
              
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" > 
        </p> 
    </form>
```

**file_upload.php**

```
<?php  
  
// session_start();
// Check if form was submited 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  
    // Configure upload directory and allowed file types 
    $rand_name = rand(1, 10000);
    // $upload_dir = 'C:/fileUpload/'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    // $permit = 0777;
    $allowed_types = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif'); 
    $upload_dir = mkdir('C:/fileUpload/'. $rand_name .'/'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 0777);
      
    // Define maxsize for files i.e 10MB 
    $maxsize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;  
  
    // Checks if user sent an empty form  
    if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))) { 
  
        // Loop through each file in files[] array 
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) { 
              
            $file_tmpname = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]; 
            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]; 
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key]; 
            $file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
  
            // Set upload file path 
            $filepath = $upload_dir.$file_name;
  
            // Check file type is allowed or not 
            if(in_array(strtolower($file_ext), $allowed_types)) { 
  
                // Verify file size - 10MB max  
                if ($file_size > $maxsize)          
                    echo "Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.";  
  
                // If file with name already exist then append time in 
                // front of name of the file to avoid overwriting of file 
                if(file_exists($filepath)) { 
                    $filepath = $upload_dir.time().$file_name; 
                      
                    if( move_uploaded_file($file_tmpname, $filepath)) { 
                        echo "{$file_name} successfully uploaded <br />"; 
                    }  
                    else {                      
                        echo "Error uploading {$file_name} <br />";  
                    } 
                } 
                else { 
                  
                    if( move_uploaded_file($file_tmpname, $filepath)) { 
                        echo "{$file_name} successfully uploaded <br />"; 
                    } 
                    else {                      
                        echo "Error uploading {$file_name} <br />";  
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            else { 
                  
                // If file extention not valid 
                echo "Error uploading {$file_name} ";  
                echo "({$file_ext} file type is not allowed)<br / >"; 
            }  
        } 
    }  
    else { 
          
        // If no files selected 
        echo "No files selected."; 
    } 
}  
  
?>
```

Please Help!

Thank you in Advance

Comment: `mkdir` returns a `boolean` so assigning `$upload_dir=mkdir(.....)` is probably NOT what you want

Comment: dump the $_FILES array to see how it's structured... then fix your code according to the true structure... honestly, I wonder how people want to program if they don't KNOW how their data looks like...

Comment: FYI - the 3rd argument to `mkdir` is worth using as it'll ensure the generation of all folders in the path which can be useful

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I have structured $_FILES accordingly then too unable to solve my issue

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Sorry Sir. I am unable to connect with your answer. If possible can you provide me some more details on the question.

Comment: Read the documentation on how $_FILES array looks like... not YOU have to stucture it, PHP does that... if you don't follw its structure, then your loop is simply incorrect: `foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value)`

Comment: @LarsStegelitz then why does it upload to direct folder. Like as when I used first $upload_dir it does upload to the folder.

Comment: @AmanVishwakarma - what do you not understand? It is quite simple - you cannot assign `$upload_dir=mkdir(...);` because that would result in `$upload_dir` being either TRUE or FALSE - neither of which is a valid directory. The answer by @cOle2 below  is on the right lines except that it also uses `.'/'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` at the end but it should not.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Ok Sir, Thank you Sir. Now I get a point where is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir` returns a boolean (true or false), not the created directory path.

You probably want to define the path in `$upload_dir` but not assign the result of the mkdir to it:

```
$upload_dir = 'C:/fileUpload/'. $rand_name .'/';

if (mkdir($upload_dir, 0777)) {
   //process images
}
```